# PowerShell Send-MailMessage to multiple recipients with differing information in the body

Tags: sql, powershell, csv, email

I have a sql script that pulls records into a csv based on specific criteria. The csv will typically look like this example:

```
Ticket,Last Updated,Priority,Assigned To,Email
2329,1-12-2017,Medium,Assignee1,assignee1@domain.tld
2417,5-23-2016,Low,Assignee1,assignee1@domain.tld
2416,4-20-2017,Medium,Assignee2,assignee2@domain.tld
2463,8-9-2016,Medium,Assignee2,assignee2@domain.tld
2481,3-4-2017,Low,Assignee3,assignee3@domain.tld
2499,2-22-2017,Medium,Assignee4,assignee4@domain.tld
2500,12-20-2016,High,Assignee5,assignee5@domain.tld
2498,11-30-2016,Medium,Assignee5,assignee5@domain.tld
```

***Note*** that the email field can have the same email address for multiple rows.

I am having trouble understanding how I should parse this data in PowerShell so that I can send the row data to the address in the `Email` column for that row.

I do not want to send multiple emails to the same person when this script runs however. So if the `Email` column has identical values in the csv I would like send one email with multiple rows of information in the body of the email before moving on to the next until EOF.

In the example csv above only one email would go to `assignee1@domain.tld` for `Ticket 2329 & 2417` data and so on until EOF. I am doing an `Order By Email` in the sql query that gets dumped to the csv if that helps organize the process.

I have used PowerShell to send emails previously but those scripts do not need to parse the data for a specific email address as the `-to` in the `Send-MailMessage` has always been static. Example from another script:

```
$FromAddress    = "noreply@domain.tld"
$ToAddress      = "something@domain.tld"
$Subject        = "Mail message Subject line"
$SMTPserver     = "smtp server address"


if ((Get-Item "data.csv").length -gt 0kb)
{
    $html = import-csv -Path .\data.csv | Foreach {$_.web_link= '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>' -f $_.web_link,$_.author;$_} | Foreach {$_.web_link= '<a href="{0}">{1}</a>' -f $_.web_link,$_.title;$_}| 
    Select @{Name="Link"; Expression={$_.web_link}}, @{Name="Author"; Expression={$_.web_link}} | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlformat -Body $bodyformat
    $html = $html -replace "&lt;","<" -replace "&quot;",'"' -replace "&gt;",">"
    $body = $notice + $html
    Send-MailMessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -bodyashtml ($body | Out-String) -priority High -smtpServer $SMTPserver 
}
else {exit;}
```

As a PowerShell novice (at best) I am wondering what my options are. I am assuming I will be looping through the csv quite a bit and potentially building out arrays. I just want to make sure, for my own education, that the task is accomplished in the simplest form PowerShell allots us.

Thanks.

Comment: You could use `Group-Object` to group by `Email`

Comment: Thanks for this comment. Seems a silly thing for me to miss, but again, PowerShell is not my forte. I added working code as the answer using your suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if ((Get-Item "import.csv").length -gt 0kb)
{
$import = Import-Csv -Path .\import.csv|
Group-Object -Property Email -AsHashTable
    foreach ($i in $import.GetEnumerator()){
        $html = $($i.Value) | ConvertTo-Html -Head $htmlformat -Body $bodyformat
        $html = $html -replace "&lt;","<" -replace "&quot;",'"' -replace "&gt;",">"
        $body = $notice + $html
        Send-MailMessage -from $FromAddress -to $ToAddress -subject $Subject -bodyashtml ($body | Out-String) -priority High -smtpServer $SMTPserver
    }

}
else {exit;}
```

Above is a snippet example of how we got this working. I left out some of the html formatting variables as they are unimportant. I also have yet to test sending not to a static email address but to the email address from `-Property Email` I am assuming that replacing `$ToAddress` with `$i` should do, or something close.